# Python pandas pivot_table margins keyError

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Consider the following dataframe:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'A': [datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.datetime.now()], 'B': [1, 2]})
```

If I use `pivot_table` like below then everything is fine:

```
test.pivot_table(index = 'A', aggfunc = {'B': 'mean'}, margins = True)
```

However, if I do the following, I can't set `margins = True` (throws the error `KeyError: 'A'`):

```
test.pivot_table(index = test['A'], aggfunc = {'B': 'mean'}, margins = True)
```

I am really confused. Let's say I need do something like below AND need to set `margin = True`. Is that impossible?

```
test.pivot_table(index = test['A'].dt.year, aggfunc = {'B': 'mean'}, margins = True)
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not change anything. Same issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
test['Ax']=test['A'].dt.year

test.pivot_table(index = 'Ax' , aggfunc = 'mean', values='B', margins = True)
```

Outputs:

```py
        B
Ax
2020  1.5
All   1.5
```

**Explanation**: in case if you don't pass `values` it will default to `df.columns` (all columns of dataframe, that you're pivoting over). https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.25.3/pandas/core/reshape/pivot.py#L87

So technically by passing no `values` you were passing ALL columns into `values`, yet at the same time providing function for just one, so this is where this `KeyError` was coming from.

Source here is oddly off with the documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html